# Office add-in onReady no longer loading environment

Tags: office-js

I have an Office add-in that works in Word, PowerPoint and Excel. Everything has been working perfectly, and I am/was very happy.  We started the certification process to list our add-in on the Marketplace, and MS came back with some feedback on a couple of items to fix.

I added those items to the code, and all good. Yay. Simple enough.

Yesterday I went to take new screenshots, and nothing works.  And by "nothing works" I mean I am getting the following error after my add-in loads:

```
Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.
```

I am calling Office.onReady() at page load, and making sure that the office environment is initialized before making any calls.
But all of a sudden I am getting this response in the console...

I havent changed anything - has anyone else noticed this?

I dont even know what I can do to further troubleshoot the issue -

Comment: Does your add-in have a task pane? If so, is it loading and rendering?

Comment: Did you make changes to the manifest? Open the taskpane/index.html in Edge, do you see any console errors?

Comment: Sorry - I forgot I had asked this question.  After more investigation it turned out that a component I was using was not set up correctly and was causing this issue - the error displayed incorrectly pointed me to an issue with office.onReady...

I removed the component and everything was back to normal